# How do I prevent x labels from overlapping my bars in a barplot?

Tags: r, powerpoint

Here is the code:

```
barplot(colMeans(sample_data, na.rm = TRUE),
    las = 1,
    main = "Main Title",
    xlab = "Variable",
    ylab = "How Characteristic",
    col = rainbow(20),
    cex.names = 0.9,
    horiz = FALSE)
```

A sample data set is available here:

https://github.com/akaEmma/public_data/blob/master/sample_data.csv
Or you can type some of it in yourself. These are the variable names:

```
Love of Chocolate,Asian Knowledge,Stable Cleanliness,Love of People,Attention,Ethics,Aggression,Swimming,Style Points,Felinity
```

And here are some of the data that go with the names:

```
8.67    9   6.25    7.33    6.33    5       6.67    5   5.25
8       3   6       6.67    8       7       7.67    4.5 5.25
7.33    7.5 5.75    8.67    8.67    8       5.33    2.5 3
8       6.5 6       6.33    8.33    5.33    5.67    6   6.5
6       5.5 5.25    5.33    5       4.67    4       4   3.5
7.67    7   6       4.67    7.33    5.67    7.67    5   3.75
8.67    8   7.5     5.67    7.33    5       8.33    7   7.75
```

If I use the code above I get the following (ignore the periods; they aren't important):

[image: Small Image that doesn't have good labels]

If I create a larger plot (like fill my screen with it) I get this:

[image: Now the labels overlap the bars.]

(ignore the missing label; I accidentally left it off and it's supposed to be "Felinity," whatever that is)

This sort of bar chart is for a PowerPoint on a huge screen, so I can go very small with the labels.

Here is what I want: I want clean pretty labels, one per bar, and since this is a wish list, I want the labels to adjust their own sizes so that they are small enough to fit one per bar, and I want them to be at the right vertical point so that they do not overlap with the bars. Any ideas?

Go crazy. I want beautiful bar charts and I have to make a lot of them, so twiddling for each one is simply not an option. This has to work every time with data files of this type regardless of the length of the variable names.

Thanks!

Comment: `theme_set`,`ggthemes::theme_tufte` are for `ggplot`s, **not for base R plots**.

Comment: Ack you're right. I took that line out. It doesn't make any difference to the output, though.

Comment: Yes, they don't make a difference *because* of that. If you want to use `theme_tufte` you need to use `ggplot2`. See my answer below.

Comment: Oh, and I don't mind changing the code so it calls ggplot or ggplot2

Comment: The *library* is called `ggplot2`, while the *function* is `ggplot`. Confusing, I know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that `theme_set` and `theme_tufte` are `ggplot2`-specific functions.

Using `ggplot2` you can do something like this

```
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akaEmma/public_data/master/sample_data.csv")

library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
df %>%
    gather(key, value) %>%
    group_by(key) %>%
    summarise(mean.value = mean(value, na.rm = T)) %>%
    mutate(key = factor(key, levels = key[rev(order(mean.value))])) %>%
    ggplot(aes(key, mean.value, fill = as.numeric(key))) +
    geom_col() +
    theme_tufte() +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rainbow(5), guide = F) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6)) + 
    labs(x = "", y = "How characteristic")
```

[image]